# How to create a single feature/segment from connected line segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, merge

I want these 3 connected line segments to be a single feature/segment.

I used dissolve and unsplit tools but I am not getting desired output.

I dont want it done manually with merge tool, because I have lot of features like these.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 (ArcInfo license).

[image]

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What results do you get? And which parameters did you provide? Dissolve is meant to be exactly what you want so you have to provide some information what you actually tried.

Comment: i simply want these three segments to be a single segment

Comment: It's not possible to make these a single segment. The best you can hope for is a *three*-part line feature.

Comment: What about **buffering** the selected line segments with a very low buffer distance and enabling the **dissolve** option, **convert** the output polygon layer back into a line layer, add the feature back into the original line layer?

Comment: I think Vince is the correct answer, with Joseph's answer only helping if your rule is that all line segments that group together will touch each other or have their ends within the small buffer distance.  You can buffer a small distance with a dissolve that does not create multi-part polygons.  Use the Spatial Join tool with the lines as the targets and the buffer polygons as the Join layer to attribute the lines with the buffer polygon ObjectID value.  Then dissolve the lines on buffer OID dissolve field and check the box to create multi-part features.  Makes a 3-part line feature.